# Create 3D shapes in C#

Tags: c#

Hello I want to create 3D shapes in C#. shape that we can rotate around and change it. what kind of project should I use? Can I create it in windows form?
for example I wrote a code of creating Beam in Windows form and I want to show a 3D view of a Beam shape in program window.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) framework to create a user interface capable of displaying 3D graphics. Microsoft has a great tutorial on this topic which you can view here: [WPF 3D Graphics Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)